# How specify description in chrome developer dashboard?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm not able to specify the bolded description text separately from the description beneath.  They're both showing up as the same text, just one is larger and bold:

[image]

A simple question, but I can't seem to easily find any clear documentation on it.  Is one specified in the manifest and the other specified via the developer dashboard?  If so, that doesn't seem like an easy way to manage that user-facing copy.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/description

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just about the appearance of a listing in the Chrome Web Store, not about developing Chrome extensions/apps.

Comment: @RobW I disagree that this should be considered off-topic. Wrong tag - maybe, we have [tag:chrome-web-store].

Comment: Anything that involves the manifest.json file (which this does) is part of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in the [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard). Uploaded a picture of mine, but removed my app info.

Fill out the detailed description box, outlined in black.

[image]

Comment: The text I place in the `Detailed description` box is repeated twice, though.  In the red circle of the OP, the bold and non-bold text is the same.

Comment: @tarabyte I only see one line repeated twice. 'Bodbot is a personal trainer, nutritionist and coach.' Are you sure, that doesn't exist in the detailed description. The description in manifest, is the short description in bold.

Comment: That's it.  Description in manifest vs description in developer dashboard.  Really bizarre to have that UI controlled in two separate places.

Comment: Post the above as the answer: You need descriptions in both places, one fairly short, and the other (Dashboard) somewhat longer.